# Что такое пул констант времени выполнения?

Tags: java, терминология

Читаю про архитектуру JVM и данное сочетание слов не объясняется. Конкретно не понятно что означает приставка "времени выполнения"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921010/what-is-run-time-constant-pool-and-method-area-in-java

Comment: По идее это означает лишь то, что константы хранятся в оперативке только пока выполняется к-л программа. До запуска программы значения констант нигде не хранятся и по завершении программы из оперативки удаляются.